# Trouble with 8-bit Carry Lookahead Adder in Verilog

Tags: verilog, adder, carry-look-ahead

[image]
I'm new to Verilog programming. I'm trying to work up to a 64-bit CLA by building a 4-bit CLA, then an 8-bit (out of 2 instances of a 4-bit), then a 16-bit (out of 2 instances of the 8-bit one). I'll provide my code, then an explanation of the problem I'm having. Code:

```
// 4-BIT CLA CODE
module CLA4Bit(A, B, carryIn, carryOut, PG, GG, Sum);
    input[3:0] A, B;
    input carryIn;
    output carryOut;

    output PG;
    output GG;

    output[3:0] Sum;
    wire[3:0] G, P, C;

    assign G = A & B;
    assign P = A ^ B;
    assign Sum = P ^ C;

    assign C[0] = carryIn;
    assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
    assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & G[0]) | (P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
    assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & G[1]) | (P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) | (P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);

    assign PG = P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0];
    assign GG = G[3] | (P[3] & G[2]) | (P[3] & P[2] & G[1]) | (P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & G[0]);
endmodule

// 8-BIT CLA CODE
module CLA8Bit(A, B, carryIn, carryOut, Sum);
    input[7:0] A, B;        
    input carryIn;
    output carryOut;        
    output[7:0] Sum;

    // Block Propagate (BP) and Group Propagate (BG)
    // for each 4-bit CLA "Block"
    wire [1:0] BP, BG;

    // carryPipe that represents the carryIn for each
    // 4-bit CLA group. Calculated by the 2-block LCU
    wire [1:0] carryPipe;

    // Lookahead Carry Unit (LCU)
    LCU2Block LCU8Bit(carryIn, carryOut, BP, BG, carryPipe);

    // The two 4-bit CLA blocks that make up the 8-bit CLA

    CLA4Bit block1(A[3:0], B[3:0], carryIn, carryPipe[0], BP[0], BG[0], Sum[3:0]);
    CLA4Bit block2(A[7:4], B[7:4], carryPipe[0], carryPipe[1], BP[1], BG[1], Sum[7:4]);
endmodule

// 16-BIT CLA
module CLA16Bit_8Bit(A, B, carryIn, carryOut, Sum);
    input[15:0] A, B;
    input carryIn;
    output carryOut;
    output[15:0] Sum;

    // Block Propagate (BP) and Block Generate (BG)
    wire [1:0] BP16Bit, BG16Bit;

    // carryPipe that represents the carryIn for each
    // 8-bit CLA group; Calculated by the LCU
    wire [1:0] carryPipe;

    // Lookahead Carry Unit (LCU)
    LCU2Block LCU16Bit(carryIn, carryOut, BP16Bit, BG16Bit, carryPipe);

    // The 2 instances/"blocks" of 8-bit CLAs that 
    // make up the 16-bit CLA

    CLA8Bit block1(A[7:0], B[7:0], carryIn, carryPipe[0], Sum[7:0]);
    CLA8Bit block2(A[15:8], B[15:8], carryPipe[0], carryPipe[1], Sum[15:8]);
endmodule

// THIS IS THE LCU THAT CALCULATES THE CARRIES
module LCU2Block (carryIn, carryOut, BP, BG, carryPipe);

    input carryIn;
    output carryOut;

    // Block Propagate (BP) and Block Generate (BG)
    // represent the Group Propagate (PG) and Group
    // Generate (GG) of each "Block" of CLAs that are using
    // a particular LCU
    input[1:0] BP, BG;

    // carryPipe represents the carryIn for each 4-bit group of a 16-bit CLA,
    // and every 16-bit group of a 64-bit CLA.
    output[1:0] carryPipe;

    assign carryPipe[0] = BG[0] | (BP[0] & carryIn);
    assign carryPipe[1] = BG[1] | (BP[1] & carryPipe[0]);
endmodule
```

I wrote a simple testbench to test my code:

```
module CLA_TB(); 
    // Inputs
    reg[15:0] A;
    reg[15:0] B;
    reg carryIn;

    // Outputs
    wire carryOut;
    wire[15:0] Sum;

    CLA16Bit_8Bit CLA16Bit_8BitDUT(
    .A(A),
    .B(B),
    .carryIn(carryIn),
    .carryOut(carryOut),
    .Sum(Sum)
    );

    initial
        begin
        assign carryIn = 0;

        // Answer should be
        // Sum = b0000 0000 0000 0010 = h0002
        assign A = 16'b0000000000000001;
        assign B = 16'b0000000000000001;

        #20
        // Answer should be
        // Sum = b0000 0000 0100 1001 = h0049
        assign A = 16'b0000000000010010;
        assign B = 16'b0000000000110111;

        #20
        // Answer should be
        // Sum = 0000 1001 1110 1101 = h09ED
        assign A = 16'b0000011001011100;
        assign B = 16'b0000001110010001;

        #20
        // Answer should be
        // Sum = b0001 0101 1110 1110 = h15EE (with overflow carry!)
        assign A = 16'b1011011111010011;
        assign B = 16'b0101111000011011;

        #20
        $finish;
        end
endmodule
```

So the problem I'm having is that the 16-bit CLA correctly calculates all the 4-bit Sums properly EXCEPT for the second one from the left, which is seen as an X (please refer to picture).

I know that X's are displayed in Verilog when a wire has more than one driver (signal source), and I recently found out that it'll also display an X if a wire isn't given a value or if Z is used in an expression (however, I never used Z in any expression in my testbench).

I know that my carryOut is a "Z", but that wire is just a leftover from back when I was experimenting with different implementations of the CLAs - I shouldn't even have dragged that to the Wave graph for display. It is never used in the calculation of the carries (please refer to the CLA/LCU code).

I tested my 4-bit and 8-bit CLAs already; both work perfectly fine and add accurately despite the Z in the carryOut line, so I really don't think that's the problem.

I don't understand why this is happening. My only guess is that it has something to do with how the two LCUs (the one for the 8-bit CLA and the one for the 16-bit CLA) interact, maybe something's going wrong there?

I'm still trying to fix the problem, but I'm basically stumped so I decided to post here for help. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you asking here again? I answered the **exact** same question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459722/trouble-with-8-bit-carry-lookahead-adder-in-verilog

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned to carryout in the first module. This means it's Z or X which will propagate.

It's always a good idea to check module inputs and outputs in your simulator to see where the X comes from.